# Question about Html Encoding

Tags: c#, jquery, security, jquery-plugins, datatable

I am using jquery datatables and MS XSS library.

I did this

```
AntiXss.HtmlEncode(MyDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"))));
```

this renders this

```
07&#47;22&#47;2010 4&#58;04 PM
```

So its all encoded. Now for whatever reason this messes datatables up. It can't figure out how to sort anymore.

So why is it encoding the slashes and dots? what is so bad about them? when it is displayed in the browser is looks like     07/22/2010 4:04 PM

So I am guessing that datatables just takes in the encoded version and doesnot know what to do with it.

What should I do. I want to encode the data but if it messed up my sorting thats not good too. Should I use safe html fragments instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I am not aware of an XSS attack that involves slashes and dots.  However *many* characters have an htmlentitiy equivalent and it is making this conversion,  but i don't think this is due to a security concern.

In terms of security the **nasty** characters are these 4: `'"<>`.  Another thing,  the method `AntiXss.HtmlEncode()` should be used on user input to prevent XSS.  It doesn't make much sense to run this function on the date which cannot be influenced by an attacker... (Unless of course your defending against time travelers.)

Comment: Well the date is set by the user. I guess it would die if trying to get into the database(since it would not be a datetime). On a side note is better to encode input to the db or let everything in and encode output to user. Or do both?

Comment: How about number stored as ints? Could they right it in int's liek they can write it in hex?

Comment: Now that I think of it your right probably does not make sense to do it on dates. I guess I was thinking well the users could change it to anything(since it gets changed to a string) but I guess that is kinda hard to make a string when the date is stored in a datetime in the database and thats where I get it. So I am guessing it would be the same thing with int's, bits, etc?

Comment: @chobo2 Its *usually* better to store the data in its actual form because it makes it easier to do comparisons.  In this case you might want to select all rows after a particular date and if it was encoded you couldn't do that.   An XSS vulnerability only exists if the attacker can force another browser to execute JavaScript,  thus storing `<script>alert(/xss/)</script>` in the database isn't a vulnerability,  but printing it out is.

Comment: Ya I guess my thinking(or lack of thinking) was that for some reason they could store that in the database where my date was(even though it was a datetime)

Comment: The next version (a couple of weeks away) is slightly more circumspect in what it encodes, especially around the basic punctuation. But yes, don't store encoded data, encode at the point of rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of encoding the date just do a sanity check on the format of the date string. As long as its a well formed date there is no danger of a script injection or other shenanigans.